# An expandable command that adds a string to an argument if the string is missing

Tags: macros, expl3, expansion, programming, xstring

I would like to write and expandable command which adds a string S1 at the beginning of another string S2 if S2 does not start with S1 in order to ensure that my string always start by S1.

I currently have this code that relies on the xstring package

```
\NewDocumentCommand\forcebeginwith{m m}{%
    \edef\expandedstring{#1}%
    \edef\expandedbeginning{#2}%
    \IfBeginWith{
        \expandedstring % String
    }{
        \expandedbeginning % Beginning
    }{
        \expandedstring % String
    }{
        \expandedbeginning\expandedstring % Beginning + String
    }
}
```

For example :

```
\forcebeginwith{fancycolor}{fancy} % fancycolor
\forcebeginwith{color}{fancy} % fancycolor
```

**Question:** I would like to convert this command into an expandable command `NewExpandableDocumentCommand` but I have no idea of how to do that (I would like the resulting code to work on versions of latex dating from let's say 5 years ago so I would like to avoid super duper recent commands/packages).

Comment: Can you expand your code to make a minimal example we can compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `\forcebeginwith` is defined with `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`. The test is performed with `\str_if_eq:eeTF`. The command `\forcebeginwith` can be used inside `\edef` as in the example below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand { \forcebeginwith } { m m }
  {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF {#2} { \str_range:nnn {#1} { 1 } { \str_count:n {#2} } }
      {#1}
      { #2#1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\forcebeginwith{fancycolor}{fancy}\\% fancycolor
\forcebeginwith{color}{fancy}\\% fancycolor
\edef\testA{\forcebeginwith{LaTeX}{La}}\testA\\
\edef\testB{\forcebeginwith{TeX}{La}}\testB
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you add `\ifdefined\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\else\usepackage{xparse}\fi`, this compiles from TeX Live 2018 on.

Comment: If I define `\newcommand{\latexstr}{LaTeX}` and `\newcommand{\lastr}{La}` then `\forcebeginwith{\latexstr}{\lastr}` will return `LaLaTex`, so there is a bug in the provided code. How to avoid the bug?

Comment: @Vincent For reference: this question is answered with your question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/708414/problem-with-a-command-that-prefixes-words-only-if-needed-when-the-arguments-are

Comment: @Vincent This is not precisely a bug: as a string, `\latexstr` starts with `\latex` and not with `\lastr` thus `\lastr` will be placed before `\latexstr` resulting in `\lastr\latexstr` which expands to `LaLaTeX`.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `pdflatex`, then you can do it with

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\forcebeginwith}[2]{%
  \ifnum\pdfmatch{^#2}{#1}=0 #2\fi#1%
}

\begin{document}

\forcebeginwith{fancycolor}{fancy}% fancycolor

\forcebeginwith{color}{fancy}% fancycolor

\edef\testA{\forcebeginwith{LaTeX}{La}}\testA

\edef\testB{\forcebeginwith{TeX}{La}}\testB

\end{document}
```

[image]

I tested it as far as TeX Live 2012.

Answer (score 3):

The following, LuaLaTeX-based solution defines a user macro called `\forcebeginwith`. It should work with versions of the LaTeX kernel that are well more than a decade old, as the properties of the  `\directlua` primitive haven't really changed since its first appearance. Because `\directlua` is expandable, so is `\forcebeginwith`. Note that the arguments of `\forcebeginwith` need not be ASCII-encoded; instead, they're allowed to be UTF8-encoded.

[image]

```
% !TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\directlua{% Define the Lua function 'forcebeginwith':
```

```lua
   function forcebeginwith ( s1 , s2 )
      if unicode.utf8.sub ( s1 , 1 , unicode.utf8.len ( s2 ) ) == s2 then
         return ( s1 )
      else
         return ( s2..s1 )
      end
   end
```

```tex
}
\newcommand\forcebeginwith[2]{%
   \directlua{ tex.sprint ( forcebeginwith ( "#1" , "#2" ) ) }}

\newcommand\Za{color}
\newcommand\Zb{fancy}

\begin{document}
\obeylines % just for this document
\forcebeginwith{fancycolor}{fancy}
\forcebeginwith{color}{fancy}

\smallskip
% Demonstrate that '\forcebeginwith' is expandable
\forcebeginwith{\Zb\Za}{\Zb}
\forcebeginwith{\Za}{\Zb}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`  has been in `xparse` since 2016

Comment: @JosephWright - Thanks. I've streamlined the exposition to focus on the age of `\directlua`.

Answer (score 3):

Using only TeX primitives, the code should be like this:

```
\def\forcebeginwith#1#2{\fbwA .#1\end .#2\end{#1}{#2}}
\def\fbwA #1#2\end #3#4\end #5#6{%
   \ifx #1#3%
      \ifx \end#4\end #5% S2 is included at the start of S1, print S1 only
      \else 
          \ifx \end#2\end {#5} shorter than {#6}, something wrong%
          \else \fbwB {#2\end #4\end {#5}{#6}}%
          \fi
      \fi
   \else #6#5% S2 isn't inluded at the start of S1, print S2S1.
   \fi
}
\def\fbwB #1\fi\fi#2\fi{\fi\fi\fi \fbwA #1}

% test:

\message{\forcebeginwith{fancycolor}{fancy}}

\message{\forcebeginwith{color}{fancy}}

\bye
```

Note that TeX doesn't work with "strings", there are tokens lists only.

Comment: If I define `\newcommand{\latexstr}{LaTeX}` and `\newcommand{\lastr}{La}` then `\forcebeginwith{\latexstr}{\lastr}` will return `LaLaTex`, so there is a bug in the provided code. How to avoid the bug?

Comment: You should decide what is the contents of the parameters, which are given when `\forcebeginwith` is used. If the first parameter is `\lastr` (i.e. a single token) and second is La (two tokens), then the first parameter doesn't include the second one. Maybe, you want to sent expanded part of the given parameter to the processing: i.e. `\expandafter\forcebeginwith\expandafter{\lastr}{La}`. Then this is expanded to `\forcebegin{LaTeX}{La}` and this gives desired result.