# Problem with a command that prefixes words only if needed when the arguments are provided through macros

Tags: macros, expl3, expansion, programming, strings

Consider the following code coming from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708396/17200) answer, where it adds a prefix to a word, only if the prefix is missing.

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand { \forcebeginwith } { m m }
  {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF {#2} { \str_range:nnn {#1} { 1 } { \str_count:n {#2} } }
      {#1}
      { #2#1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\mystringa}{fancycolor}
\newcommand{\mystringb}{\mystringa}
\newcommand{\mystringc}{\mystringb}

\newcommand{\prefixa}{fancy}
\newcommand{\prefixb}{\prefixa}
\newcommand{\prefixc}{\prefixb}

\begin{document}
\forcebeginwith{fancycolor}{fancy}    \\% OK: fancycolor
\forcebeginwith{color}{fancy}         \\% OK: fancycolor
\forcebeginwith{\mystringc}{\prefixc} \\% NOT WORKING: fancyfancycolor
\end{document}
```

**QUESTION:** How to make it work given that I need the command to be expandable?

Comment: Fully expand the value before testing?

Comment: I'm just not familiar with `expl3` syntax, so how to do that?

Comment: Well, you can generate a variant of the function.

Comment: Off-topic: don't end lines with `\\` outside special environments. Especially not before a paragraph ends.

Comment: Could you provide a working code?

Comment: Done. I've added a bit of explanation, too, so it doesn't just look like magic. Though, actually, it sometimes feels like magic after wrestling with `\expandafter`s!

Comment: @Vincent You can find some documentation of expl3 by running the command `texdoc interface3`.  The argument specifications are in chapter 1, and these string functions are in section 16.5.

Comment: @Teepeemm Bit of a steep learning curve, though ;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given an expl3 base function, you can generate a variant which processes one or more of the arguments prior to passing the results to that function. For example, if a function has an argument specifier (the bit after the colon) `n`, you can define a variant which has `o` (expand **o**nce) or `e` (expand **e**xhaustively) in place of `n`. Then you simply use the variant wherever required.

In this case, we want variants of two functions

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_range:nnn { enn }
```

This ensures `\str_range:enn` exists. This variant will expand the first argument before handing it over to the function `\str_range:nnn` for processing.

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_count:n { e }
```

This ensures `\str_count:e` exists, which expands its only argument before passing it to `\str_count:n`.

Then we can use these variants just as we would the base functions

```
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand { \forcebeginwith } { m m }
  {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF {#2} { \str_range:enn {#1} { 1 } { \str_count:e {#2} } }
      {#1}
      { #2#1 }
  }
```

[image: variants expand arguments before processing so all three lines result in the same result]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_range:nnn { enn }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_count:n { e }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand { \forcebeginwith } { m m }
  {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF {#2} { \str_range:enn {#1} { 1 } { \str_count:e {#2} } }
      {#1}
      { #2#1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\mystringa}{fancycolor}
\newcommand{\mystringb}{\mystringa}
\newcommand{\mystringc}{\mystringb}

\newcommand{\prefixa}{fancy}
\newcommand{\prefixb}{\prefixa}
\newcommand{\prefixc}{\prefixb}

\begin{document}
\forcebeginwith{fancycolor}{fancy}    \par% OK: fancycolor
\forcebeginwith{color}{fancy}         \par% OK: fancycolor
\forcebeginwith{\mystringc}{\prefixc} \par% NOT WORKING: fancyfancycolor
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_range:nnn  { enn }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand { \forcebeginwith } { m m }
  {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF {#2} { \str_range:enn {#1} { 1 } { \str_count:e {#2} } }
      {#1}
      { #2#1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\mystringa}{fancycolor}
\newcommand{\mystringb}{\mystringa}
\newcommand{\mystringc}{\mystringb}

\newcommand{\prefixa}{fancy}
\newcommand{\prefixb}{\prefixa}
\newcommand{\prefixc}{\prefixb}

\begin{document}
\forcebeginwith{fancycolor}{fancy}    \\% OK: fancycolor
\forcebeginwith{color}{fancy}         \\% OK: fancycolor
\forcebeginwith{\mystringc}{\prefixc} \\% NOT WORKING: fancyfancycolor
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A better programming style is to define the user level command in terms of an internal function.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand { \forcebeginwith } { m m }
 {
  \vincent_forcebeginwith:ee { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \vincent_forcebeginwith:nn
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeF {#2} { \str_range:nnn {#1} { 1 } { \str_count:n {#2} } } { #2 }
  #1
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \vincent_forcebeginwith:nn { ee }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\mystringa}{fancycolor}
\newcommand{\mystringb}{\mystringa}
\newcommand{\mystringc}{\mystringb}

\newcommand{\prefixa}{fancy}
\newcommand{\prefixb}{\prefixa}
\newcommand{\prefixc}{\prefixb}

\begin{document}

\forcebeginwith{fancycolor}{fancy}    % OK: fancycolor

\forcebeginwith{color}{fancy}         % OK: fancycolor

\forcebeginwith{\mystringc}{\prefixc} % OK: fancycolor

\end{document}
```

As you see `\vincent_forcebeginwith:nn` is defined, but in the user level command we use a variant thereof that fully expands its arguments before handing them over to `\vincent_forcebeginwith:nn`.

[image]